# Limit superior and inferior of a set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, double-sequence

If $S=\left\{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}\mid p, q\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ then $\varlimsup S-\varliminf S=?$

**My attempt** since derived set of S is$\left\{\frac{1}{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}\cup \{0\}$ and so by taking difference of greatest and smallest limit point of above set we find $$\varlimsup S-\varliminf S=1$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Put $p=q=1$ to see $2\in S$.

Comment: @PeterMelech of cource $2\in S$ but What is the answer of the question?

Comment: So $2=\lim\sup S$ and $\lim\inf S=0$ as You observed...

Comment: Note that $\sup S=\max S=2$, $\limsup S=1$, and $\inf S=\liminf S=0$

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Sure! Thanks , a rather silly mistake

Comment: @user697748 I'm sorry $\lim\sup =1$ see Hagen's comment